# How to add ripple effect to ionic div?

Tags: ionic-framework

I found this   `<ion-ripple-effect></ion-ripple-effect>`
But, it's only to element ripple, not ripple around click (with specific radius)
[image]

Comment: `<div class="ion-activatable ripple-parent">
      A plain div with a bounded ripple effect
      <ion-ripple-effect></ion-ripple-effect>
    </div>`

Comment: and? how it can help?